# Kernel32.dll to read card SD like file. Read long space

Tags: c#, sd-card, kernel32

I read card SD like file. I use this method:

```
    public static int ReadUSBDisk(ref byte[] buffer, int sector, string fileName)
    {
        ushort count = 10;
        bool retValue;
        int address = 512 * sector;
        if (!IsUSBOpen())
            hUSBDisk = OpenUSBDisk(fileName);
        if ((int)hUSBDisk == -1)
            return NISH_ERROR;
        SetFilePointer(hUSBDisk, address
        , 0,
        EMoveMethod.Begin);
        retValue = ReadFile(hUSBDisk, buffer, 512, ref count, IntPtr.Zero);

        if (retValue)
            return NISH_NO_ERROR;
        else
            return NISH_ERROR;

    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool ReadFile(IntPtr handle,
    byte[] buffer, ushort toRead, ref ushort read, IntPtr lpOverLapped);

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern uint SetFilePointer(
    IntPtr hFile,
    int lDistanceToMove,
    int lpDistanceToMoveHigh,
    EMoveMethod dwMoveMethod);
```

But I need to read from more space than the int. But change lDistanceToMove to long couses throw error:

> A call to PInvoke '(className) :: SetFilePointer' has upset the
> balance of the stack. Probable cause is a mismatch between the managed
> PInvoke signature and the unmanaged target signature. Check that the
> calling convention and signature parameters of the PInvoke function
> match the unmanaged target signature.

Honestly, I don't know exactly how it works. Maybe someone can tell me if I can change it to read from long space in some way.

Comment: Why are you using PInvoke to read a file? What's wrong with good ol' `File.ReadAllLines()`

Comment: @Persistence I'm using somebody else's part of the program. I don't read the file, only the SD card which I treat as a file. The card is 32gb, reading it all at once is out of the question. But from what I'm testing it this way, I can't read it.

Comment: Does card work from a File Explorer?  First you have to determine if the right driver is installed.  File Explorer will verify the driver.  Than the cards have different addressing/data sizes 8/16/32/64.  The size of your app and the size of the card have to be consistent.

Comment: @jdweng Neither the size of the card, nor the driver version, nor the relative size of the app respective to the size of card, could result in a managed exception of a misaligned stack after a call to a standard Windows function.

Comment: Even if you need to read extremely large data [Memory Mapped Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile?view=netcore-3.1) are built in?

Comment: @SilnyToJa The signature for `SetFilePointer` is `int (IntPtr, int, ref int, int)`. You have `int (IntPtr, int, int, int)`. In any case you don't need it because you can [construct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=net-5.0#constructors) a `FileStream` from a Windows file handle, if you insist on using those.

Comment: @jdweng I don't know if I understand you well, but this card has no filesystem, it only has data sectors in byte. After connecting to the reader, windows displays a message that the card should be formatted. I can read this full content with the help of the program HxD.

Comment: I think the driver is wrong.  The program HxD is using an internal driver while you are using the installed driver for the card.   I would check what driver is being used in Device Manger.  Try downloading a new version of the card read driver.  File Explorer should show files unless the app is using a different format.  A old card reader may not work with newer cards.  Or the driver may not support a newer format so driver needs updating.

Comment: @jdweng No, the HxD program is not using an internal driver, nor is there a way for Explorer to magically come up with a list of files on a drive with [no file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68099707/kernel32-dll-to-read-card-sd-like-file#comment120362761_68099707). Please stop [spreading misinfomation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392514/11683).

Comment: [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/SetFilePointer.html) is very helpful source to get correct signature for invoking.

Comment: @GSerg : The SDisk driver there is a low level driver and upper level driver.  In this case only a low level driver is used.  The low level driver has to be compatible to the partitioning of the disk.

Comment: @Sinatr overriding the SetFilePointer method
static extern bool SetFilePointerEx (IntPtr hFile, long liDistanceToMove,
    IntPtr lpNewFilePointer, uint dwMoveMethod); solved the problem. Thanks